# JQuery: Получить список из всех элементов, у которых нет класса

Tags: jquery

Пример кода:
http://jsfiddle.net/28nxu/1/

Тут при клике на кнопку происходит добавление класса 'checked' к кнопке.

Далее я получаю список всех значений (атрибут value) кнопок, у которых есть класс 'checked'.

Вопрос: как можно получить список всех значений кнопок, у которых нет класса 'checked'?

Comment: Вам нужна именно такая реализация?
jQuery умеет работать с $('.selector:checked')

Comment: checked - это в данном случае не атрибут, а класс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как можно получить список всех значений кнопок, у которых нет класса 'checked'?

используя `:not()` в селекторе или метод `.not()`:

```
$('.zn_button:not(.checked)');
$('.zn_button').not('.checked');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/28nxu/2/

Comment: Нужен селектор именно по id="spoiler_surface", т.к. таких блоков будет ещё несколько.

Comment: > Нужен селектор именно по id="spoiler_surface"

Так?

    $('#spoiler_surface :not(.checked)');

> именно по id="spoiler_surface", т.к. таких блоков будет ещё несколько.

Давайте сыграем в игру. Любой желающий может сказать, сколько блоков с одинаковым id может быть на странице, а я говорю, верно ли это число.

Comment: Спасибо.
Естественно id будет у блоков уникальный, просто обрабатывать их нужно будет по отдельности.